# Push Notification in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I am beginner in Android development. I want to develop an app where in students will receive notices of college by push notification in an app.

I have searched for push notification but getting answers related to [GCM](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html) only.

Please help by explaining how to test the server to app push notifications in eclipse itself, without using external entities or Internet.
Thank you.

Comment: If you are not using GCM, then please explain **completely and precisely** what you are planning on using for push notifications. You might also want to explain what "external entities" are.

Comment: The best working [Push Notification Example for Android](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/)

Comment: @Kedarnath I dont recommend that one because it uses GCMRegistrar which is deprecated use this http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/gcm/GoogleCloudMessaging.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use RestClient like Postman, Advance RestClient (Chrome extension), Simple RestClient (Chrome extension) to send or test notifications.